# Упала тактовая частота памяти gpu NVIDIA rtx 2060

Tags: nvidia, видеокарта

Видеокарта NVIDIA rtx 2060. После обновления винды , заметил что производительность в играх уменьшилась. Смотрел через NVIDIA Geforce Experience и заметил что частота GPU колеблется в районе ~1900 MHz , а тактовая частота памяти не превышает 7000 MHz , я загуглил и посмотрел что частота GPU должна быть диапазоне 1365–1680 , а тактовая до 14000 MHz . Ещё температура дикая , только захожу в игру сразу поднимается до 80 градусов , при том что степень загрузки ГП не превышает 50%. Драйверы свежие . Не знаю что делать :/

Comment: Почистить от пыли?

Comment: @KoVadim , я тоже про это подумал в первую очередь , взглянул , а радиатор чистенький как будто только купил.

Comment: Тогда либо просто драйвера плохие, либо радиатор отстаёт. Я бы поменял температуру радиатора. Если он сильно холодный, значит плохо пристает и видяха тротлит

Comment: @KoVadim , а замена термопасты как-то поможет ? :/

Comment: только при условии, что Вы ее умеете менять. Если никогда этого не делали, то можно только навредить.